# Zend project : Do not permit the source code displaying

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, security, php

This morning, I was afraid when I discovered that it is possible to display by default the `http://www.mydomain.com/application/configs/application.ini` file of my Zend project!

And more disturbing, it is possible to display the php source code of the `.phtml` page when pointing the final URL like `http://www.mydomain.com/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml`

Therefore, I really need to protect my web site. I am sure that it is possible to prevent the `.ini` file and source code displaying using the right syntax of the main `.htaccess` located in the `public` folder.

Could you help me?

I thought about this kind of syntax, but I won't copy the `.htaccess` file into all my folder. I would like write the rule only into one file.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .*\.(phtml|php)$ - [F]
```

**EDIT**
My directory structure is :

```
ProjectDir
 |_application
 | |_configs
 | |_controllers
 | |...
 |
 |_public
 | |_index.php
 | |_css
 | |_js
 | |_.htaccess
 |
 |_library
   |_Zend
```

Comment: post your directory structure and current .htaccess

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using the standard Zend directory tree

Comment: Could you explain the down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems to be one directory too low.

The web root seems to be your "ProjectDir".

In this directory you only want to have the contents of your public folder.

The application and library directories need to be one level up. You should be able to do this with your hosting interface.

Your structure should look like this if you cannot modify the vhost:

```
|_application
|
|_library
|   |_Zend
|
|_ProjectDir
    |_index.php
    |_css
    |_js
    |_img
    |_.htaccess
```

Comment: I have been working on a project where I need to have the entire Zend Application in the public folder due to the production server setup.

I have the following in the .htaccess to hide the application code:

RewriteRule application/.* - [F]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Where did you put your .htaccess to hide the application code?

Comment: In my case I had all the code in the root directory (ProjectDir in your setup), so I put the .htaccess file there.

Answer (score 1):

The appication directory should not be in a public directory (it should be outside your web root).

A normal directory tree for a zend project should be like this (whith web root pointing to ProjectDir/public/):

```
ProjectDir
 |_application
 |
 |_public
 | |_index.php
 | |_css
 | |_js
 | |_img
 | |_.htaccess
 |
 |_library
   |_Zend
```

... etc

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my application folder is not included into my public folder. I am using the standard directory tree like you described above

Comment: Not sure to know exactly what is a webroot point, but my web site entry point is : http://www.mydomain/public/index.php

Comment: That's the problem, your webroot is poiting to ProjectDir/ instead of ProjectDir/public/. Your website should be accessible from domain.com/index.php not domain.com/public/index.php. You need to edit you configuration and point the web root to /path/to/ProjectDir/public/

Comment: Ok, I understand. At this time, my domain.com/index.php file is :   header('Location: public/index.php'); I don't have access to the httpd.conf, because my project is hosted by an internet provider. How/where can I set the right configuration web root?

Comment: do you want to keep accessing your website with domain.com/public/index.php ? or do you want it to be domain.com/index.php

Comment: when you access your host server with ftp, what structure do you have ?

Comment: My Zend project is one of the folder present on my FTP web directory

Comment: If you want to access you website with only domain.com/index.php. then you must take your application and library directories in their precedent dir, and also move everything in public directory to it's precedent. If you do that, you will be able to access your site with domain.com/index.php and you application/configuration etc won't be accessible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16689/discussion-between-bouillou-and-yazmat)

Comment: Not now, I have to go out sorry

Comment: Thans for your time and advices